# Prevent compulsive trashing on macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, finder, catalina, trash

We have an autistic teenage girl with a compulsive behavior to move files to the trash and empty it! Is it possible to prevent just the emptying of the trash?

Comment: Does it help (i.e., interrupt the compulsive behavior) if you turn on the trash warning? (Finder→Preferences→Advanced→Show warning before emptying trash) Otherwise you'll be looking at odd solutions (like a script that moves things out of the trash as soon as they are put in there).

Comment: What does macOS do if you let Finder create ~/.Trash, and then change the permissions to 000 and the ownership to root:root?  I recognize that since said teen still has rights on $HOME, they could remove the Trash directory and let Finder recreate it, but if they don't know that, would this slow them down?  OTOT, it might just offer "Delete immediately".